# Detailed Explanation on how to use ListView renderSectionHeader

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, react-native-listview

```
const users = 

    [

        {
          name: "Joy soap",
          customerName: "Salomy",
          date: "19 March 2018",
          time: "08:46am",
          amount: 3000,
          status: "paid",
          number: 24,
          images:
            "https://snack1.amazonaws.com/~asset/9d799c33cbf767ffc1a72e53997218f7"
        },
        {
          name: "Closeup tooth paste",
          customerName: "Salomy",
          date: "19 March 2018",
          time: "08:46am",
          amount: 3000,
          status: "paid",
          number: 20,
          images:
            "https://1.amazon4d99c3d76575cc03c2a7f816280"
        },
        {
          name: "Iman Powder",
          customerName: "Emanbe",
          date: "20 March 2018",
          time: "11:25am",
          amount: 3000,
          status: "paid",
          number: 12,
          images:
            "https://1.amazonaws.com/~asset/ee06c63d01543a44631c3421df6ee5fa"
        },
        {
          name: "John Bellion",
          customerName: "Okonkwo Chioma",
          date: "20 March 2018",
          time: "08:46am",
          amount: 3000,
          status: "paid",
          number: 3,
          images:
            "https://sn1.amazonaws.com/~asset/ee06c63d01543a44631c3421df6ee5fa"
        }
      ];
```

Please I have an array of objects like the above that I want to render in a ListView with a Section Header function pointing to user.date... I want it to render a list of all the items on 19 March 2018, and then render the items on 20 March 2018 under the header also.
I have used ListView several times but I have never been able to use the section header in this way with the above arrays of object. Please a detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated. I know its probably a simple task to some of you but please be kind. I need a renderSectionHeader() **function** that can organize the data with respect to their dates so I can render it in my listview like this

```
`<ListView
            ref={ref => (this.scrollView = ref)}
            onContentSizeChange={() => {
              this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false});
            }}
            dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader.bind(this)}
          />`
```

An example of what I want is [here](https://www.google.com.ng/amp/s/moduscreate.com/blog/react-native-listview-with-section-headers/amp/) but I want to know how it can be done with the above array

Answer (score 0):

**ListView is no longer available in React-Native.** You can use **FlatList**. Its very simple then ListView as well.

1) Import FlatList from react-native:

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
```

2) Copy Below code into your **render()** method.

```
         <FlatList
                horizontal={true/false}
                style={YOUR_COSTOM_STYLE}
                data={YOUR_ARRAY}
                renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
            />
```

3) You do necessary stuff for your cell in **renderItem** method.

```
// Render Methods
    renderItem({ item }) {
        return (
            // DO_YOUR_STUFF
        );
    }
```

You can more detail about FlatList from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html).
 One more example for [header in FlatList](http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/FlatListExample.html)

Comment: I want to know how its done in ListView please... And you said nothing about renderSectionHeader

Comment: I want to be able to use renderSectionHeader... Not just loop through it

Comment: There is an option available in FlatList. Just check list which I attached.

Comment: Wow, it seems very useful even though I have never used it before... So do you have a working example of how I can use the listViewHeader props in FlatList

Comment: I gave you an example for FlatList. You can add your header/footer as you want. Refer link, you will get more idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want a working example please... Of how to loop through an array of objects

Comment: renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
This is run a look. renderItem will call till your array count.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ng/amp/s/moduscreate.com/blog/react-native-listview-with-section-headers/amp/

Comment: Thats the example I want to build but I want to know the function I can use to get section ID and dataBlob with the above array of objects

Comment: Checkout this example: http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/FlatListExample.html

Comment: I wont ... Thanks alot